# Text Input Controller WatchKit

Tags: swift, watchkit

I am trying to use `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions` in a `WatchKit` app.
I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(["Hello", "Hey"], completion: { 
    (myString) -> Void in
    println(myString)
    })
```

Comment: What is the error ? Is the text input controller not showing up ?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Does anybody know how to set up a listener/delegate that returns, during dictation, the speech recognition result at any given moment, while dictation is still taking place??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [iOS 8.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.2/index.html):

> ## WatchKit
>
> ### Known Issues
>
> The presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:completion: method of
>   WKInterfaceController is not currently supported in iOS Simulator.

Comment: Ah okay. That explains it! Thank you

Comment: On beta 3 it is already supported https://twitter.com/schemetrical/status/546108083089313792

Answer (score 5):

You can try by tapping on a suggestion. It should do exactly the same as dictating.
Beware, the completion returns an array and not a string.
You should do it like that

```
self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(["Suggestion 1", "Suggestion 2"] allowedInputMode: .Plain, completion: { (selectedAnswers) -> Void in
    if reply && reply.count > 0 {
        if let spokenReply = selectedAnswers[0] as? String {
            println("\(spokenReply)")
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there any way to customizer the modal that pops up with suggestions? Like say if I wanted to change the color of the options

Comment: Not as I know. Note that if you don't have any recommendation to display, you can jump directly to dictation by passing an empty recommendation array. In the simulator you will see a white screen but it works.

Comment: @prawn It's probably a bit late, but you can change your apps "Key Color" which will change the text input buttons to that color

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Dev Forums

Its the same a pressing microphone on the iPhone keyboard and dictating.

The Audio goes off to apple and returns and hopefully the text you spoke is returned as a String.